# A large number of contacts have never been synced to Pardot: why?

Tags: pardot, sync

We have about 12K contacts in our org, of which 11K have an email address. More than 800 have not been synced to Pardot. I verified this via samples and via querying the Contact.pi__created_date__c field.

There are almost no sync errors in Pardot. The user that Pardot uses to connect has the standard sysadmin profile. So far we have not been able to find the distinguishing characteristic that determines why most contacts get synced, but some do not.

Also: how do we force those 800 to be synced?

Comment: Looking at a related question, I see a remark that I have found elsewhere as well: "the contacts were created before pardot was implemented with Salesforce, so they would need to be manually uploaded into pardot". This is true for almost all contacts, but maybe someone imported not all contacts present in Salesforce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created an import file for Pardot for the missing contacts and started the import. And the result shows me why the contacts were missing in Pardot: almost all of them have info@ and sales@ email addresses, which are not permitted to be imported.

So probably, originally, these contacts have also been imported by Pardot and also been rejected. But that fact had been forgotten or the people who did it are no longer with the company.